In Laravel, I want a page history not be stored in browser history. How to prevent user using "back" button to see the old page
am working with CRUD project Laravel using Modal for: create, delete, update. But there is a situation when user from Home Page go to a Room Page. In the Room Page, they will click the update button and the Modal Update pop-up for user to edit data of the Room and after that they click submit. When they submit it will redirect them to the Room Page itself for user to watch the data they just updated.
But the problem is when user click on Submit, it will save the old page (before edit) to the browser history and redirect them to the new page (after edit). So now when they stand at new Room page (after edit) and when they click back in browser, they will see the old Room Page (before edit).
I don't want that, I want the old page remove from the browser history after submit so the user will not see the old page after edit even when they click on the back button.
The problem encountered: Home Page ====> Room Page (old page) ===submit===> Room Page (new page after updated)
What I want is the old page being removed from history after submit: Home Page ====> Room Page (new page after updated).
// Controller

// Show view

public function daytro()

{

// Lấy data ra ngoài để in ra màn hình

$daytros = DayTro::paginate(5);

// echo $savedUrl ;

//dump($currentUrl);

return view('pages.daytro', compact('daytros'));

}

// Update

public function update(Request $request, $id)

{

// Tìm ra trường thông tin cần update => Lấy ra tập data

$daytro = DayTro::findOrFail($id);

// Nếu validate thấy vị phạm nó sẽ lưu error vào session và nhảy tới redirect() ngay lập tức

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

'tendaytro' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:daytro,tendaytro,'.$id,

'tinh' => 'required|string|max:255',

'huyen' => 'required|string|max:255',

'xa' => 'required|string|max:255',

'sonha' => 'required|string|max:255',

], [

'tendaytro.unique' => 'Tên dãy trọ vừa cập nhật đã tồn tại',

]);

if ($validator->fails())

{

return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator, 'update_errors_' . $id)->withInput();

}

// Đưa tất cả các thông tin đã update vào DB để sửa

$daytro->update($request->all());

$daytro->save();

// Hiện thị thông báo thành công

flash()->option('position', 'top-center')->success('Dãy trọ đã được cập nhật thành công!');

// $daytros = DayTro::paginate(5);

// return view('pages.daytro', compact('daytros'));

// return redirect()->back();

return redirect()->back();

}


You can't control anything in the browser from PHP. There are some things you can do using the History API in JavaScript - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API to understand what is possible.

Ultimately though, if the user decides to go back, they should be able to understand that this means they are seeing an old version of the page, because they went back - and they should hopefully remember that they only updated it a few moments before! If they fail to understand that, that is really the user's problem, not your application's problem. What issue do you think will happen if they decide to view the old page?

Moreover, if you want such, you must go for SPA frameworks. (Ex: Angular). You can even prevent going back in Laravel. But still, browser saves the history

@TrongTue That’s not how web apps work I’m afraid, buddy. Why are you deliberately trying to break browser functionality?
